# Unable to apply patch

Tags: composer, version-control

I am unable to apply patch using composer in Drupal core 8.6.4. Can anyone help me to apply patch using composer?
Here is the process what I am doing :

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": " ^1.25",
    "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.1",
    "drupal/config_split": "^1.4",
    "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.5",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.3",
    "drupal/s3fs": "^3.0-alpha13",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0-beta1",
    "drush/drush": "^9.4",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
    "drupal/restui": "^1.16",
    "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0-alpha4",
    "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.0",
    "drupal/colorbutton": "^1.1",
    "library-ckeditor/panelbutton": "^4.11",
    "library-ckeditor/colorbutton": "4.11.1",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.1",
    "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "^2.2",
    "drupal/migrate_file": "^1.1",
    "drupal/taxonomy_import": "^1.0",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.7",
    "predis/predis" : "^1.1.1",
    "drupal/rabbitmq": "^1.1",
    "php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle": "^1.14",
    "drupal/ultimate_cron":"^2.0-alpha4",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "asm89/twig-lint": "^1.0",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
    "drupal/coder": "^8.2.12"
},
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.6"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
        "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
        "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
        "https://www.drupal.c/node/2718229"
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": true,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    },
    "enable-patching": true,
    "patches": {
        "drupal/core": {
            "Search autocomplete from views result": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-10/2174633-238.patch"
        }
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
    "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit phpspec/prophecy symfony/yaml --with-dependencies --no-progress",
    "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
    "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "library-ckeditor/panelbutton",
            "version": "4.11.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/panelbutton/releases/panelbutton_4.11.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "library-ckeditor/colorbutton",
            "version": "4.11.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/colorbutton/releases/colorbutton_4.11.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Command: composer install - but nothing happens.

Comment: Unless the patches plugin doesn't provide a composer apply-patches command or similar, you can simply delete your `composer.lock` file prior to `composer install`. Off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Even I have also tried `composer update --lock` but nothing happens.

Comment: Ain't the drupal/drupal project's outdated and must be converted using grasmash/composerize-drupal. Can you check that?

Comment: Thanks, @leymannx for your suggestion. I got the issue and it is working fine. Actually, I am trying to apply the patch on core files so need to add this in require not in replace. Ex : `"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.6"
}` should be in `"require": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.6",
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",}`

Comment: How did you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 'composer require cweagans/composer-patches' in order to apply patches.